# javascript for menu generation and displaying data in table

Tags: c#, javascript, sql-server

I am generating a menu using an unordered list (ul) and I want to display some specific data on a mouseover event of each li. I also want to add data to a gridview. The data to be displayed is related to the value in li and is to be fetched from a SQL database.

I was wondering if anybody could give me any suggestions as to how I might go about doing this?

P.S. I am using C# on the server side.

Comment: http://jquery.com/ seems to be a popular starting point for making web applications more "2.0" feeling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use add onmouseover attribute while generating your LI nodes.

```
<li onmouseover='yourjavascriptcode'></li>
```

You can find example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms970713.aspx). Adding attributes to server side controls is explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7ytf5t7k.aspx).

I think the best solution is to use jQuery to match your elements, and attach mouseover event:

```
$('#yourUlID li').mouseover(
  function() {
    //your js code
  }
);
```

Example [here](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/).

If you want to add data fetched from database to the html table I do not recommend using gridview. Just use Ajax and put fetched data into simple and light html table. If you don't know how to use Ajax with jQuery [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-ajaxjquery.html) article should be helpful for you.